# after uninstalling ubuntu the boot entry is still there

Tags: system-installation

I had an error during the install of ubuntu so when I uninstalled it, the boot entry was still there. I wish to attempt a reinstall, but this is not working, and I think the boot entry is the problem. I was installing Ubuntu 12.10, if that is of any importance.

I had installed it on a windows 7 system.

Answer (score 0):

If the grub menu is the issue, you'll have to do some careful editing to get it to work. I am not sure what your exact setup is, but I'll assume that you want to reinstall ubuntu on the same drive or partition that the old uninstalled setup was on. I am fairly sure there is an option to reinstall or upgrade ubuntu, or at last resort format the driver/partition and then install, under the custom install option when you boot from the external installation device. Also remember to hit a key like F11 (varies by computer) to choose which boot medium you use when your computer is initially turning on to actually reach the installation process.

Edit: If you just want to remove the grub entry, just do a quick search and find something like http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/clean-up-ubuntu-grub-boot-menu-after-upgrades/